# Google App Engine isolated from App

Tags: google-app-engine

About an hour or so ago, my app was cut off from Google App Engine.  All my 3000+ users have no access to the server.  The GAE log has stopped recording.  I have checked all the status of the server and its all green.  Nothing in logs or admin logs.  Cron job failed to run.  There has been no change on the code since last month and the app has been running smoothly for the last 3 years.  I'm not sure where to go to next.  My credit card on file should still be current and the maximum daily budget has not been reached.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my question.  Apparently Google App Engine did have problems for 2 hours.  They are back now. Thanks.